# Remove poll icon in primefaces

Tags: primefaces, icons, primefaces-mobile

How do you hide the primefaces poll icon ? My poll interval is 1s so it's quite annoying when it shows up every second. Should I work with the class attribut ?

My current code :

```
<pm:content>
    <h:form>
        <h:outputScript library="primefaces/poll" name="poll.js"/>
        <p:outputLabel id="idCurrentOnlineTime" value="Current Online Time : #{partnerPromotion.currentOnlineTime}s"/>
        <p:outputLabel id="idTotalOnlineTime" value="Total Online Time : #{partnerPromotion.totalOnlineTime}s"/>            
        <p:poll  interval="1" update="idCurrentOnlineTime,idTotalOnlineTime"  />
    </h:form>
</pm:content>
```

Comment: Don't use poll, use websockets. Way more modern, future proof etc

Comment: I'll use it for server notification. But here, it's just a timer. I think I could use only javascript on clientside but for sake of simplicity (because I don't know enougth js) I used poll.

Comment: Why do you add `poll.js` manually? PrimeFaces takes care of including its scripts.

Comment: Not with primefaces mobile unfortunatly

Answer (score 0):

`p:poll` by itself doesn't have any visual representation. You probably have something like `p:ajaxStatus` on the same page. You can specify:

```
<p:poll global="false" ...
```

, then its requests won't trigger `p:ajaxStatus`.